# Odd spacing at the top of html5 boilerplate demo

Tags: html, css, html5boilerplate, boilerplate

I downloaded the HTML5 Boilerplate template from here http://html5boilerplate.com.

When I opened it to preview the template; I see an odd space on the top. It can be seen on their online demo also: http://demo.html5boilerplate.com/

[image]

I see this on the following:

- FireFox v28
- Chrome v34.0.1847.116
- Internet Explorer v11

---

CSS In Use:

- http://demo.html5boilerplate.com/css/normalize.css
- http://demo.html5boilerplate.com/css/main.css

---

I had a look at the page's html source and the css stylesheets. I can't figure out where this odd spacing on top of `<p>` tag is coming from.

Comment: You should look into using some tools for web development. In Chrome, for example, if you simply right click on the element and select "inspect element" a panel will open up that will allow you to trace where the rendering of any element on the page is coming from. All web browsers have similar tools. That's how the correct answer below was derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's default user agent style

```
p {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

You need to define your own style for `<p>` element.
Is that what you mean?

Comment: I had to add `padding: 0; margin: 0;` also and it appears to remove the odd spacing on top now.

Comment: FWIW, it's not really "odd." That's the default rendering  of a paragraph in a web browser. That's what "default user agent style" refers to, it's the standard way in which web browsers render content without any CSS applied.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there is a 16px margin to the top and bottom of the `<p>` tag.